# github actions - Private Composite action POST fail

Tags: github-actions

**Issue:**

Pulling a private repo that contains several actions will fail in the POST phase with error message:

```
 Error: Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' under '/home/runner/work/testjerome/testjerome/.github/actions/package_and_push_to_ECR'. Did you forget to run actions/checkout before running your local action?
```

Example to reproduce it:

```
- name: Check out main repository
  uses: actions/checkout@v2

- name: Get composite run steps repository
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
    repository: myorg/myaction
    # Select revision
    ref: v1.0.0
    # Personal access token to check out private repository
    token: ${{ secrets.PAT_TOKEN }}
    # Indicate where to check action out to
    path: .github/actions

- name: Run action from private repo
  uses: ./.github/actions/myAction
```

This example assumes that "myorg/myaction" is a private github repo with 1 folder having 1 file like this: myAction/action.yml

**Question:**

Would any one know how to avoid that issue, while still having several actions in a repo ? (yes, I could create 1 repo per action ... but this is going to be messy)

**References:**

This is a follow up from the comments from [How do you use a composite action that exists in a private repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69034292/how-do-you-use-a-composite-action-that-exists-in-a-private-repository)

As well as this github issue (can't find the issue itself in github):
https://githubmemory.com/repo/actions/runner/issues/1300

Someone did setup a reproducible example:
https://github.com/rethab/composite-action-user

Comment: You can have multiple actions in the same private repository as well if it makes sense in your context. Check this question's answer (which was posted yesterday): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69705595/github-actions-multiple-action-in-a-single-repo

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the question - found the github issue link:
https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/1300

I'll wait until someone helps there

Also, as the issue is "because we do a checkout action in the remote action", the workaround I'm now using is:

- remove that checkout
- upload the files I need from the caller job, and download them from the callee ... silly workaround for a silly issue